# getting error while creating android sqlite table. error given: missing date column

Tags: android, sqlite

getting error in get-information method it throws an error saying missing column name date: could you please tell me what is that I am doing wrong here. Appreciate your help in advance. Thank you

```
public class UserDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MEALINFO.DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=5;
private static final String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+ UserMeals.UserMealInfo.TABLE_NAME+"(id INTEGER, "+
        UserMeals.UserMealInfo.CAL_IN_TAKE+" TEXT, "+UserMeals.UserMealInfo.DATE+" TEXT, "+ UserMeals.UserMealInfo.MEAL_TYPE+" TEXT );";

public UserDbHandler(Context context){

    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "Database created / opened.....");

}



public Cursor getinformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projections={UserMeals.UserMealInfo.CAL_IN_TAKE,UserMeals.UserMealInfo.DATE,UserMeals.UserMealInfo.MEAL_TYPE, };
    cursor= db.query(UserMeals.UserMealInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Comment: You are missing a column.

Comment: how do I add the column?

Answer (score 1):

First at all I am wonder how you don't get "no such table error" because you never create the tables on the DB. To do that override the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method and then execute the queries needed for the tables creation on the DB.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Vlade087 said, you have to execute the query to create the table overriding the onCreate method from SQLiteOpenHelper. To add a new column in this table, or perform any change in the database model, you need to change the database version (increment it). It will call onUpgrade method where you can drop or alter this table. Generally people do this in the onUpgrade:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + UserMeals.UserMealInfo.TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```